# get table join with column value

Tags: sql, join

How can i join tables using column value?

I have three tables as listed below:

- **messages_table**

  ```
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  msg_id  | msg_sub   | msg_to    | to_user_type  | msg_from  | from_user_type
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  001     | test      | 88        | manager       | 42        | admin
  002     | test2     | 88        | manager       | 94        | manager
  ```
- **admin_table**

  ```
  -------------------------—
  admin_id    | admin_name
  -------------------------—
  001         | Super Admin
  ```
- **manager_table**

  ```
  ---------------------------
  manager_id  | manager_name
  ---------------------------
  88          | Mandela
  94          | Kristen
  ```

How can i get the desired output as shown below with SQL query. I.e.
Join tables with respect to column values when the following criteria is met:

1. If `user_type = admin` then it should join with `admin_table`.
2. If `user_type = manager` then it should join with `manager_table`.

**Desired output:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
msg_id  | msg_sub   | msg_to_name   | msg_from_name
-----------------------------------------------------
001     | test      | Mandela       | Super Admin
002     | test2     | Mandela       | Kristen
```

I.e. Get the join sql query based on column value.

---

**EDIT:**

I want to fetch the datafrom sql query not form the serverside coding.

I tried this query from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455379/630316), i.e. Winfred's Idea ( Answered )

However, I could not understand it.

`msg_by_usertype` is the column based, where the value `manager` then it should select `manager_table` and if it is admin the to `admin_table`

Comment: what are the columns you want to retrieve?

Comment: additionally how are the tables related to each other? example the messages table and the admin table? what is their linking column

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you can try this:

```
    SELECT msg_id,  
     msg_body,  
     usersBy.userName AS msg_by, 
     usersTo.userName AS msg_to,  
     msg_by_usertype
    FROM messages
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT admin_id As id, admin_name as userName
      FROM admin_table         
     UNION         
     SELECT manager_id As id, manager_name as userName
      FROM manager_table ) usersTo ON msg_to = usersTo.id  

     INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT admin_id As id, admin_name as userName
      FROM admin_table        
     UNION         
     SELECT manager_id As id, manager_name as userName
      FROM manager_table ) usersBy ON msg_by = usersBy.id
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea37d/5) to see how it works.  (It only works if you cant have an admin who has the same id like a manager. Id should be unique in both tables.)

Answer (score 3):

Please use the below SQL

```
SELECT msg_id,  
     msg_body,  
     usersBy.userName AS msg_by, 
     usersTo.userName AS msg_to,  
     msg_by_usertype
FROM messages
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT admin_id As id, admin_name as userName,'admin' as usertype
      FROM admin_table         
     UNION         
     SELECT manager_id As id, manager_name as userName,'manager' as usertype
      FROM manager_table ) usersTo 
      ON msg_to = usersTo.id  and  msg_by_usertype = usersTo.usertype
```

Answer (score 2):

if I understand your question correctly, you want a result like this?

```
MSG_ID      MSG_BODY    MSG_TO      BY           MSG_BY_USERTYPE 
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  --------------- 
001         test        adm1        managone     manager         
002         sadff       adm1        adm3?        admin
```

If so, you could use this

```
SELECT MSG_ID, MSG_BODY, MSG_TO,                                        
     CASE                                                               
         WHEN MSG_BY_USERTYPE = 'admin' THEN COALESCE(                  
              (SELECT ADMIN_NAME FROM ADMIN_TABLE                       
               WHERE  MSG_BY = ADMIN_ID), RTRIM(MSG_BY) CONCAT '?')     
         WHEN MSG_BY_USERTYPE = 'manager' THEN COALESCE(                
              (SELECT MANAGER_NAME FROM MANAGER_TABLE                   
               WHERE  MSG_BY = MANAGER_ID), RTRIM(MSG_BY) CONCAT '?')   
         ELSE ' '                                                       
     END AS BY,                                                         
 MSG_BY_USERTYPE                                                        
 FROM MESSAGES
```